# How to encode URL in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, urlencode, url-encoding

Is there a kind of URLEncode in Groovy?

I can't find any String → String URL encoding utility.

Example: `dehydrogenase (NADP+)` → `dehydrogenase%20(NADP%2b)`

*(`+` instead of `%20` would also be acceptable, as [some](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/urlencode/Encode.aspx) implementations do that)*

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You could use `java.net.URLEncoder`.

In your example above, the brackets must be encoded too:

```
def toEncode = "dehydrogenase (NADP+)"
assert java.net.URLEncoder.encode(toEncode, "UTF-8") == "dehydrogenase+%28NADP%2B%29"
```

You could also add a method to string's metaclass:

```
String.metaClass.encodeURL = {
   java.net.URLEncoder.encode(delegate, "UTF-8")
}
```

And simple call `encodeURL()` on any string:

```
def toEncode = "dehydrogenase (NADP+)"
assert toEncode.encodeURL() == "dehydrogenase+%28NADP%2B%29"
```

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(toEncode)` is deprecated.  The default encoding it uses is not recommended by RFC 3986.  It is best to use `URLEncoder.encode(toEncode, "UTF-8")`

Comment: It is a bummer that this function is not already part of the GDK URL class.

Comment: For some reason, that metaClass version didn't work for me. Because I tried it in a Gradle build script?