# Unable to import java.net.URLEncoder in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, urlencode

I'm pretty new in groovy, trying to encode a URL in my first piece of groovy code.

Here is a section of my code：

```
import java.net.URLEncoder
String url = baseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(parameter);
```

It looks quite the same as many examples I check online but it throws error as below.

```
General error during canonicalization: Importing [java.net.URLEncoder] is not allowed

java.lang.SecurityException: Importing [java.net.URLEncoder] is not allowed
```

I have also tried to use the class directly as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187344/how-to-encode-url-in-groovy)

```
String url = baseUrl + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(parameter);
```

and another version:

```
String url = baseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(parameter);
```

both throw me error:

```
General error during canonicalization: Indirect import checks prevents usage of expression

java.lang.SecurityException: Indirect import checks prevents usage of expression
```

appreciate if any guru can help clear the doubts.

Comment: Can you show us the whole code? I installed Groovy here and execute the following code: `println URLEncoder.encode("URL encoding fine!")`, it prints `URL+encoding+fine%21`.
Moreover, using `import java.net.URLEncoder` or static import also works fine.

Comment: What type and version of the JDK are you running?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java, `java.net.*` package in Groovy is imported by default, which means `java.net.URLEncoder` is also imported. Use it without import.

*Edit:* For me, using this Groovy code:

```
println URLEncoder.encode("URL encoding fine!")
```

prints `URL+encoding+fine%21`

Comment: thanks. I have tried that as well earlier but also gives me "Indirect import checks prevents usage of expression" error.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check this now, but I too found a lot of examples of using URLEncoder just as `URLEncoder.encode(string)`.

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly what puzzles me. It doesn't look like a complex stuff.