# How to delete gmail guest account using MS Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to remove a guest user from AD using graph api. For that we use the following as describe from the documentation :

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}

If the user is a user with an AD domaine that works correctly but for external user with a GMAIL account for instance, the userPrincipalName is formated as below sample :

ex : serge.cal_gmail.com#EXT#@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com

When I try to get the ID of that user by fetching first its id using :

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/serge.cal_gmail.com#EXT#@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com

It returns an error as below :

{ "error": { "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound", "message": "Resource 'serge.cal_gmail.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.", "innerError": { "request-id": "da8bdcda-6304-4c3c-93b2-6454433dcba2", "date": "2020-05-15T14:51:46" } } }

**Updated :**
Based on your comment as a test I have encode manually the userprincipal and test it under POSTMAN, that return the correct user details.

But the issue, is that as I do not know in advance the user ID that will be generated, I am using the userPricipal name of user to fetch the user ID. In Azure AD account, userPrincipal is most of the time the email address, this is what I use the the API call to get user info.

Now for cases of GUEST account which are not based on an external AD, the problem is that the only way I have to fetch the user is by userPrincipal of guest account and when I check my user AD profile, my GUEST userPricipal info is the email address as seen in picture below :

[image: Guest user Principal info]

So by using this information to API return the error of resource not found, and this is because if I fetch the user by its ID ( which I do not know except going into the AD manually which is not the goal ) I get user principal formed as below :

[image]

So in Azure AD screen the real userPrincipal form of a GUEST user is hidden in a way.

So how can I fetch it correctly ?

1 - use the API normaly as any other by using the email
2 - Then catch the error message
3 in case of error reformat the userPrincipal using the wierd syntax ?

Or Does the API offer the possibilities to fetch Guest Account, then from the guest response list of users I then search for the email adress user I need and gets it ID ?

Thanks for advise

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the `userPrincipalName` and then put it in the graph api(I test it in graph explorer). You can go to this [page](https://www.urlencoder.org/) and input the `userPrincipalName` to encode it and then copy the result to your graph api, the encoded `userPrincipalName` will be as below:

```
xxxxxx.com%23EXT%23%40xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would it be better to encode all my userPrincipalName or just for Guest account which does not use external AD like gmail ?

Comment: I forgot to ask, how can I encode using groovy script ?

Comment: @SCW If the user is native account such as "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", we do not need to use encoded `userPrincipalName`, we just need to use its email(without do encode). You can test it by some native account and some guest account in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) first and then do it in your code.

Comment: @SCW Sorry I don't know much about groovy. You may refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187344/how-to-encode-url-in-groovy) about how to encode in groovy script.

Comment: Hi @SCW You can use this api(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest'`) to filter the guest accounts.

Comment: hi @huryShen, can i combined my guest account email to that filter as well ? that will may be return only the user I am interested in ?

Comment: @SCW No, I test it in my side, it can't implement this specifical requirement.

Comment: @SCW If my answer helps your problem, could you please mark it as "accepted". Thanks in advance.